# Android - When bundling List<MyClass> use Parceling or Serializing?

Tags: android, bundle, serializable, parcelable, parcel

How should `List<MyClass>` be properly passed from the main activity to a secondary activity?

From what I understand, there are two ways to bundle data: `Parceling` and `Serializing`. What are the pros and cons to each?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link on anddev might give you answer in details
http://www.anddev.org/bundle_vs_parcel_vs_message-t517.html

Also there is one more article on the same topic. Its here
http://www.mooproductions.org/node/6?page=57

Answer (score 2):

Parcelable is significantly faster than Serializable -- last I checked, at least an order of magnitude.  On the other hand, it does require more work from you, since it doesn't do things automatically.  But that is one of the reasons it is so much faster. :)

Generically I strongly recommend staying away from Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the android developer site, [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) , [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)